# Computing the Inverse of a two dimensional map?

Tags: functions, inverse-function

In order to find the inverse of the function $y = x^3$ where $y = f(x) = x^3$

we need $x = f^{-1}(y)$, which we compute it as $x = y^{\frac{1}{3}}$ so the inverse function.

But how do I calculate the inverse map of the following map? $x \mapsto Ax +By + C$
and $y \mapsto Dx$ ?, where $A,B,C,D$ are real numbers.

I was trying to visualize this in terms of matrices, $\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} Ax + By + C \\ Dx\end{bmatrix}$, may that open up some new insights?

How can we guarantee the existence of the inverse for this two dimensional map?

Comment: What are $x,y, A, B, C$? Real numbers, integers, matrices? Also, your first statement would seem to indicate $x^2 = y  = f(x) = x^3$, was that intended?

Comment: Thank you! I just did an edit to correct the typos.

Comment: Great, I'll give this some thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x \mapsto Ax +By + C$ and $y \mapsto Dx$ can be rewritten as :

$$\left(\begin{matrix} x' \\ y' \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right)=M\left(\begin{matrix} x \\y\\1\end{matrix} \right)$$

Where

$$M=\left(\begin{matrix} A & B & C \\ D & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &1\end{matrix} \right).$$

If $M$ is invertible, then $\left(\begin{matrix} x \\y\\1\end{matrix} \right)=M^{-1}\left(\begin{matrix} x' \\ y' \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right)$.

So existence of an inverse is guaranteed by invertibility of the subjacent matrix when you have a linear system.

Which sums up here to $D\ne 0 \ne B$.

---

Note that we added a row for the affine part. By doing so, we where able to express your function as a linear system. We could have written also :

$$\left(\begin{matrix} x' \\ y' \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right)=M'\left(\begin{matrix} x \\y\\1\end{matrix} \right)$$

But the invertibility would have been more difficult to express in term of matrices.

Comment: Great answer. I just want to point out that, given that this is an upper triangular matrix, it is worth noting that the invertibility condition translates exactly to $A \neq 0$, $D \neq 0$.

Comment: Yes indeed. Should I add your remark to the answer ? @GuidoA.

Comment: Well, only if you want to :P It's clear from context if you know some linear algebra, but since I don't know OP's background I felt like making the remark.

Comment: Perhaps using the matrix $M$ we get $y' = Dy$ ? but we require $y' = Dx$

Comment: Missread, updated.

Answer (score 0):

So you have the mapping $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2\to  \mathbb{R}^2$, $f(x,y)=(Ax+By+C,Dx)$. **Claim:** $f$ has an inverse iff $A,B\not=0$. This follows from the fact that $f$ is invertible iff the linear system of equations $Ax+By=\xi-C, Dx= \eta$ is solvable for all $(\xi,\eta)\in  \mathbb{R}^2$.
**Missprint:** The condition is $B,D\not=0$

Comment: If $A = B = 1$ and $C = D = 0$, we have $f(x,y) = (x+y,0)$ which is not injective.